# Why do we kiss the tzitzit after baruch sheamar?

Tags: blessing, tzitzis, shacharis-morning-prayer, kissing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Boruch Sheomar - kissing the Tzitzis](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6737/boruch-sheomar-kissing-the-tzitzis)

Why do we kiss the tzitzit after baruch sheamar? The only connection I can think of is that Hashem created the world for us to perform mitzvot, which are symbolized by the tzitzit. But if this is the reason, shouldn't we kiss the tzitzit in the middle of baruch sheamar, right after mentioning the creation of the world, instead of at the end?